# Python File Server, login function not working

Tags: python, authentication, server

I made a python file server a while back and just recently came back to it. It is a very simple program but i wanted to add some more features to it, one of those being to add some security. For this reason i made a hashed login password and put that in a .txt file stored on the server computer. The way the program is supposed to work is every time the client connects to the server they must enter a password. Then the raw_entry is sent through a socket and checked on the server side if it is correct, if is is not then the user has two more tries to enter the password. For some reason this is not working.

The server:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import socket
import threading
import os

def login():
    loop = 1
    while loop <= 3:
        passwd = sock.recv(1024)    
        with open('passtor.txt', 'r') as f:
            hash = f.read()
            if pbkdf2_sha256.verify(passwd, hash):
                s.send("Access Granted")
                loop = 4
            else:
                s.send("Verification Failure")
                loop += 1
                if loop == 3:
                    sock.close()

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        sock.send("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename)))
        userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        sock.send("ERR ")

    sock.close()

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    #s.connect(('google.com', 0))
    host = s.getsockname()[0]
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

    print "File Server Initiated"
    print("Server Address-> " + host + " <-") 



    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print "Client Connected ip-> " + str(addr) + " <-"
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=login, args=("RetrThread", c))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("RetrThread", c))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()

    s.close()
except:
    print("Program Error, \nTermination Complete")
```

The client:

```
import socket


host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

loop = True
while loop == True:
    passwd = raw_input("Admin Password-> ")
    s.send(passwd)
    answer = s.recv(1024)
    if answer == 'Verification Failure':
        loop = True
        print(answer)
    elif answer == 'Access Granted':
        loop = False
        print(answer)


filename = raw_input("Filename? -> ")
if filename != 'q':
    s.send(filename)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
        filesize = long(data[6:])
        message = raw_input("File exists, " + str(filesize) +"Bytes, download? (Y/N)? -> ")
        if message == 'Y':
        s.send("OK")
        f = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        totalRecv = len(data)
        f.write(data)
        while totalRecv < filesize:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            totalRecv += len(data)
            f.write(data)
            print "{0:.2f}".format((totalRecv/float(filesize))*100)+ "% Done"
        print "Download Complete!"
        f.close()
else:
    print "File Does Not Exist!"

s.close()
```

Comment: I forgot to add the error message i get on the server when a client connects,                                                                                                       Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: login() takes no arguments (2 given)

Comment: add *args to your login function so it looks like this

`def login(*args):`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two arguments to the login function here:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=login, args=("RetrThread", c))
```

They are not declared in the function declaration:

```
def login():
```

Either remove the args parameter from the call to threading.Thread or add the arguments to the function declaration.

Comment: Does Anyone know why i get a error during the login function?                                                                                         s.send("Access Granted")
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe